# Failed to construct 'Blob': The 1st argument provided is either null, or an invalid Array object.

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-io

I started using filesaver.js today.I have created the following function:

```
function saving(){
    var blob = new Blob(final_transformation, {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");
}
```

but when i call that function i get"Failed to construct 'Blob': The 1st argument provided is either null, or an invalid Array object. "
Any ideas?

Comment: `console.log(final_transformation);`

Comment: the variable is not the problem.I get the result i want

Comment: You get the result you want, yet you have an error, and that would be the first argument.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since you won't tell us what `final_transformation` is, we have to guess with no context. Try this :

```
function saving(){
    var blob = new Blob([final_transformation], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");
}
```

Comment: try this var a = new Blob([""],{type: "text/plain;charset=utf-16"});a,size

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error.

See the Blob constructor documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob:

```
var aBlob = new Blob( array[, options]);
```

> `array` is an `Array` of `ArrayBuffer`, `ArrayBufferView`, `Blob`, `DOMString` objects, or a mix of any of such objects, that will be put inside the `Blob`.

So the first parameter to `new Blob` is pretty specific - it can only be an array that contains objects of several specific types.  A regular string was not working for me, but this works:

```
> new Blob( [ new TextEncoder().encode( 'some text' ) ], { type: 'text/plain' } )
< Blob {size: 9, type: "text/plain"}
```